# Тормашки - что это?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Вверх ногами - иначе говорят "вверх тормашками". Это слово явно родственно слову "тормошить". А что такое "тормашки", собственно говоря?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Неплохо бы копнуть историю торможения: не тормозили ли в каких-то случаях ногами, трением о поверхность дороги, о снег. На санках так и поступают, при этом можно и перевернуться.

Comment: Матвей Дёмин, мне тоже показалось, что то, чем тормозили сани, могло называться ножками, то есть тормами. Например потому, что тормозки на санях - явное усовершенствование, которое пришло на смену торможению ногами. Логично это приспособление продолжать называть ножками. Вот и можно на санях кувырнуться ножками вверх, то есть в конечном итоге тормашками. Человку упасть ножками кверху весьма затруднительно, обычно ножки расположатся горизонтально. Как может войти в фольклёр то, чего не бывает.
Доподлинно известно, что велосипед обзавёлся тормозами не сразу, и тормозили на нём "лаптёй". И сани,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересна версия происхождения «тормашек» от слова ТОРМАС/ТОРМАЗ - железная полоса под полозом, чтобы сани менее раскатывались. Это слово, возможно, греческого происхождения  (и.-е. корень ter – тереть). В этом случае, если сани перевернулись, то они лежат кверху тормозками / тормазками . Со временем, возможно, тормазки перешли в "тормашки".

Также существует слово "тормашка", которое, согласно Толковому словарю Ефремовой, означает "дно, основание".

Тогда получается, что вверх тормашками – это изначально ВВЕРХ ДНОМ,  что в большей степени соответствует значению этого слова.  А дальше, возможно, шло сближение значений: если   человек падает кувырком, через голову, то это вверх ногами, головой вниз, то есть вверх дном -  вверх тормашками.

Answer (score 3):

Существует несколько версий относительно значения этого слова. Слово тормашки и диал. тормашка связывают с глаголом тормошить – ‘трясти, переворачивать‘ (Михельсон; Люстрова, Скворцов, Дерягин). Однако, связь тормашки с этим глаголом вызывает сомнение. По законам русского словообразования подобные существительные создаются, как правило, не от глагольной, а от именной основы: рубаха – рубашка, птаха – пташка, таракан – таракашка и т.п. Основой тормашек был скорее всего не глагол, а существительное, а именно – диал. (рязан.) тормы/ и (дон.) торманы – ‘ноги‘, которые входят в состав диалектных оборотов вверх (кверх) тормами (тормам), вверх тороман, вверх тороманью, вверх тормани, вверх торомами. Вначале и оборот вверх тормашками употреблялся в диалектной падежной форме вверх тормашки – ср. поговорку Полетел от Машки – вверх тормашки. Источник: Грамота.ру.http://www.gramota.ru/igra/contests/archive/39_22

Answer (score 1):

Я бы отдал предпочтение словосочетанию "вверх тормами", т.е. "верх ногами". Упал ребёнок вверх ножками - тормашками, - звучит ласково, нежно.Ой, божечки, упал!..
 Сани упали вверх тормозами... упали и упали. К тому же, торма - тормашка - тормашки, тогда как, тормоз - тормозок - тормозки. Судите сами, что ближе!Люди, изучающие историю слов, т.е. этимологию, не всегда учитывают их эмоцианальную состовляющую, а ведь язык, речь - это не просто передача информации, но и выражение внутренних ощущений, открытие внутреннего мира внешнему.

Comment: Версия была бы неплохой, если объяснить, откуда взялось диалектное слово "ноги-тормы" - ведь у каждого слова есть своя этимология, свои родственные связи. Каково происхождение корня "торм"? А может быть, оно вторично по отношению к эти "тормашкам"? Также хорошо бы проследить время появления этих выражений -  вверх дном, вверх ногами, вверх тормашками.

Comment: Тогда следует обьяснить и происхождение слова "ноги".

Comment: У "ног" тоже интересная этимология, но вполне прозрачная. Слово "ноги"  является родственным по отношению к словам "коготь-ноготь" (инд.-евр. корень), экспрессивный перенос значений с животного на человека (сравнить: морда, лапа). Слово заменило прежнее "ped", которое сохранилось у нас в языке в форме "пеший".

Comment: Ноги - общеславянское слово. Надо догадаться, откуда  на Дону и в Рязани появилось диалектные выражения вида: вверх тороман, торманью, вверх торомами, где "тормы, торманы " -"ноги" http://monavisa.ru/chto-takoe-tormashki.htm

Comment: В некоторых белорусских сёлах приднепровья до сих пор глагол 
"растормошить" означает "попинать ногами". У меня лично нет сомнений относительно связи тормы-ноги, а вот относительно ног, происшедших от ногтей, есть.

Comment: Интернет-сообщество никак не разберется с "тормашками", но личной убежденностью, к сожалению, убедить других невозможно, нужны серьезные  доказательства - например, ссылки на диалектные словари.

Comment: А вы оторвитесь от интернета словарей и сходите в народ.

Answer (score 1):

Тут два варианта, оба хуже.
Либо тормашки - от тормошить, как и предполагалось в других ответах, но совершенно непонятно, почему тогда именно ими вверх.
Либо все-таки тормашки - это дно, низ, основание. Тогда понятно почему ими вверх, но этимология в этом случае загадочна.  
Скорее все-таки первое, но нужен мостик от "тормошить" к "ногам".

"Тормозами" мне совсем не нравится. Что называется за уши притянуто по случайному (или не случайному) созвучию. Да и по смыслу никак не стыкуется.

Да, насчет "мостика". В принципе-то он есть: ноги->ходить=трястить->тормошить->тормашки. Но уж очень какой-то хилый получается. Надуманный.

Вообще-то есть такая замечательная книга - Словарь русских народных говоров.
С его помощью подобная "народная" версия обычно или сразу снимается за отсутствием родового гнезда, либо получает некоторое подтверждение. Но единственное доступное мне место в сети требует доброго интерната, а я, к сожалению, таковым не располагаю. Попробую ночью туда залезть...